# wordpress slider that supports 100% width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been looking for a plugin which supports 100% width, and with no luck i havent found any without having to pay for them.

Anybody know of a WordPress plugin which supports full width. Thanks

Comment: Spend some time writing some javascript, what you need is in all honesty quite an easy javascript plugin to write.

Comment: 100% width relative to what? You should know how big your images are (in px). Then go for a free slider like http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slider Revolution](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380) and [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) at **CodeCanyon** are best sliders for WordPress you should buy them.

For Free Slider, You should try

Meta Slider, Soliloquy slider, LenSlider, Cyclone Slider, FlexSlider, Captain Slider, SlideDeck 2 Lite.